# jQuery slideUp acts differently in Firefox & Safari

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I am junior in jQuery and css and I just cannot figure out why my slideUp() & slideDown() methods behave differently in Chrome vs Firefox/Safari.

https://repl.it/J9yX

For my portfolio project, I added few images vertically. On each click, its description div shows up(slideDown()) as the other opened description disappears(slideUp()).

```
      $(".project").each(function(){
      $(this).click(()=>{
         $(".project").find('.projectDescription').slideUp()

        setTimeout(()=>{
          $(this).find('.projectDescription').slideDown(400)
        }, 400)
      })
    })
```

In Chrome, clicked image does not go above the top of the page  as its description slides down and the previous image's description slides up. It is affected by the other div's height changes until it reaches to the top of the page.
However, in Safari and Firefox, clicked image actually goes above the top of the page as the other opened description slides up and its height changes.

- example : [Firefox vs Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fF9o.gif)

I would greatly appreciate if you could explain why and how to fix this issue.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the issue you are talking about—or perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question. What does "go above the top of the page" mean?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I added an example. Please take a look at it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what problem you have and what do you want to solve because your description is a bit confusing...but let me try. I fixed the code that when you click on the same photo again, it hides and doesn't slideDown. I used flag to check if user clicked same or different photo and if it's same just skip the whole slideUp part:

```
var checkSame;
$('.project').on('click', function() {
    var photo = this.id;
    if (photo != checkSame) {
        $('.project').find('.projectDescription').slideUp();
    }
    checkSame = photo;
    $(this).find('.projectDescription').slideToggle(600);
});
```

PS. Next time don't link to the 'read only' code ;)

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I am really new at this as you can tell. I added an example of how it is behaving in Firefox browser. Please take a look at it.  Also, do you know how to change 'read only' file to 'read write' file in codepen?

Comment: [@jkoo87](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8334248/jkoo87): Still not sure what problem you have, but when i scroll down the page using my code the clicked image normally 'goes above the top of the page' both in Chrome and Firefox. I mean the image can leave the window viewport. Did you check the behavior using my code?

About 'read only' links i don't know how it goes on codepen. I'm using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and on this website everything is fine.